# Javascript, concatenate 1st element of an array to 1st element of another array

Tags: javascript, arrays, concatenation

I'm a beginner in Javascript and I'm trying to concatenate the first element of an array to the first element of a second array, the second element with the second element and so on. The 2 arrays have always the same length.

I can use only plain Javascript code. The functions in capital letters are custom functions of the platform I'm using (fulcrumapp.com).

The first array has 3 elements. The first element starts with `$1&498600&%Cocina%...`, the second one starts with `$2&498600&%Baño%...` while the third one starts with `$3&700600&%Baño 2%...`:

`var resumen_espacios = ['$1&498600&%Cocina%3611:nc2&498600&,3612:c2,3613:c2,3614:c2,3615:c2,3616:c2,3617:c2,3618:c2,3619a:c2,,,,36113:c1,36114:c1,36115:c1,36116:c1,36117:c2,,,,36121:c2,36122:c2,,$', '$2&698600&%Baño%3611:nc2&698600&,3612:c2,3613:c2,3614:c2,3615:c2,3616:c2,3617:c2,3618:c2,3619a:c2,36110:c1,36111:c1,36112:c1,,,,,36117:c2,36118:c1,,,36121:c2,36122:c2,,$', '$3&700600&%Baño 2%3611:nc2&700600&,3612:c2,3613:c2,3614:c2,3615:c2,3616:c2,3617:c2,3618:c2,3619a:c2,36110:c1,36111:c1,36112:c1,,,,,36117:c2,36118:c1,,,36121:c2,36122:c2,,$'];`

From the first array I'm extracting sub-string of the elements through the following function:

```
function extract_3611(value, index, array) {
  if (NOT(CONTAINS(STRING(value),'3611:nc'))) {
    return '';
  } else {
    return value.split('3611:nc').pop().split('&,')[0];
  }
}
```

I'm then creating a new first array as follow: `var output_3611_arr = resumen_espacios_arr.map(extract_3611);`

which output is: `['2&498600', '2&698600', '3&700600'];`

The second array has 3 elements:

`var espacios_titulos_arr = ['Cocina', 'Baño', 'Baño 2'];`

I'm then trying to concatenate the `var espacios_titulos_arr` and `output_3611_arr` arrays in the following way:

```
for (var i = 0; i < espacios_titulos_arr.length; i++) {
  SETRESULT((espacios_titulos_arr[i] + ' -> ' + output_3611_arr[i])); 
}
```

What I would like to get from the SETRESULT() function is:
`['Cocina -> 2&498600', 'Baño -> 2&698600', 'Baño 2 -> 2&700600']` but the issue is that I am always getting only the last item `['Baño 2 -> 2&700600']` as output of SETRESULT() function, independently of how many elements have the arrays I want to concatenate. Honestly, I can't understand why.

Thanks for any advice, Stefano.

Comment: what is the `SETRESULT`?

Comment: SETRESULT() is a custom function of the platform I'm using but it could be seen as console.log(). SETRESULT() basically set the result in a form field as text.

Comment: you should be putting the concatenated string into an array first then pass  that array to SETRESULT

Comment: @PatrickEvans, thanks, something like Bartosz proposed below? Because I tried but it didn't work. I'm always getting the last element.

Comment: No, they call SETRESULT inside the loop and use that to set the array value. You dont want to call SETRESULT at all in the loop. Call it after the loop after creating the array. [Kevin](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58959986/560593)'s answer should work

Comment: I got it, thanks, Kevin's answer worked perfectly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Array.prototype.map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map).

```js
result = espacios_titulos_arr.map((s, i) => s + ' -> ' + output_3611_arr[i])
```

then use `SETRESULT` as needed.

```js
SETRESULT(result)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also try the following:

`` var output = espacios_titulos_arr.map((item, index) => `${item} -> ${output_3611_arr[index]}`) ``

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
var resultArray = [];
for (var i = 0; i < espacios_titulos_arr.length; i++) {
    resultArray.push(SETRESULT((espacios_titulos_arr[i] + ' -> ' + output_3611_arr[i]))); 
}
```

after that loop, You have Your results in result array

Comment: Thanks but unfortunately it didn't work I'm always getting the last element.

Comment: You are setting the array elements to the value of `SETRESULT` which probably doesnt have a return value. You should be making the array from the strings, then sending that array to SETRESULT. Eg `SETRESULT(resultArray)` outside the loop